# Connect to gtalk when there is another connection in one activity

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, google-talk

I want to make an application, where in one activity I can play Video Streaming via video-view,  show information via web-view, and chatting, I have succeed to make the video streaming using video view, and show information but when I add the chat in that activity, the chat isn't worked when try to log in using port 5222, and host `talk.google.com` (in log cat there is  some error message, one of error is :

```
can't connect to `talk.google.com` request time out)
```

Is that because the connection problem only or, it must be another method to use gtalk and that xmppp port in my application ?

Comment: show your xmpp configuration parameter please.

Comment: ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
===============================================
Declaration :
 public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
 public static final int PORT = 5222;
 public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";